# Pages languages and format not working properly

Tags: html

My pages are displaying in chinese, 
URL: [mytodo.just-flick.com/index.html](http://mytodo.just-flick.com)

i am not sure what is the probelm

When I am using the same html on my laptop, its working fine. 
Please help I dont know whats wrong with this.

Comment: +1 Because it's a great example of why character encodings are important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing UTF-16 and UTF-8 and possibly some other character encodings as well. And you don't specify the character encoding in the document.

I'm not gonna explain how character sets and character encodings works, since other people have done that already. I'd recommend this blog post for you:
http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

After you've read that you can come back and ask any questions you might have.